# What overwrites an alias created by a file in /etc/profile.d? (environment variables)

Tags: 20.04, bash, environment-variables, 22.10, alias

I executed the following command to create an alias file in CentOS 7.9:

```
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/alias-ll.sh
```

Then once I restarted the shell, "type ll" indicated that this alias did not work. I thought this may have been due to another file in /etc/profile.d overwriting the alias, so I renamed the file to "z-alias-ll.sh". Then I restarted shell and this time, "type ll" indicated that the alias had worked successfully.

However when I do the same in Ubuntu 20.04, "type ll" indicates that it does not work. There were some filenames like "Z99-cloud-locale-test.sh" and "Z99-cloudinit-warnings.sh" in /etc/profile.d in Ubuntu, so I tried these:

```
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/Z99-alias-ll.sh
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/ZZ99-alias-ll.sh
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/Z99-z-alias-ll.sh
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/ZZ99-z-alias-ll.sh
echo 'alias ll="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/Z99Zalias-ll.sh
```

However, when I restart the terminal, "type ll" still says, "ll is aliased to `ls -alF'".

If I make another alias file:

```
echo 'alias lltest="ls -alhF --color=auto"' > /etc/profile.d/alias-lltest.sh
```

Then after I restart the terminal, "type lltest" indicates that this file is being sourced. So, I think the alias files in /etc/profile.d are being sourced, but the alias for "ll" is being overwritten somehwere.

Since I tried prefixing with "ZZ99" etc. I don't think it's an string sorting issue, like with CentOS 7.9, where I had to add the "z-" prefix to the filename to prevent another /etc/profile.d file from taking precedence. However, I am not 100% sure.

What file, script, etc., might be taking precedence over the alias files I created in /etc/profile.d? What takes precedence over /etc/profile.d in Ubuntu, in terms of defining environment variables?

I tried on both Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.10, using fresh Digital Ocean droplets.

Comment: If "the terminal" means a terminal *emulator*, such as `gnome-terminal`, then by default in Ubuntu it likely starts an *interactive non-login* shell - which reads `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` rather than the various `profile` files

Comment: Thank you. By terminal, I meant the Digital Ocean droplet console. I did a test where I placed different aliases for the same command in /etc/bash.bashrc and /root/.bashrc, and a file in /etc/profile.d. It seems that the order of precdence is ~/.bashrc > /etc/profile.d > /etc/bash.bashrc. There was already an alias for "ll" in /root/.bashrc, that was the cause of my issue. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: It's not a precedence, rather, whatever comes last wins. And bash does read system-wide configuration before user configuration and it does read profile before bashrc for interactive login shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, user settings have precedence over system wide settings. This is also valid for aliases. User defined aliases have precedence over aliases defined at the system level. By default on Ubuntu, `alias ll='ls -alF'` is defined in the user's `.bashrc` file, thus overriding any alias you may have set elsewhere.

Comment: and alias ls='ls -ALf' will overide the default system ls command.